# series.add doesn't add new series

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I've modified XYseries demo for charting with Android using AChartEngine.  It doesn't add the second array as a new series. Here is my code.

```
 private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset() {
     XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    final int nr = 10;


    double[] test1=new double[] {121.0,122.0,123.0,124.0,125.0,126.0,127.0,128.0,129.0,130.0};
    double[] test2=new double[] {131.0,132.0,133.0,134.0,135.0,136.0,137.0,138.0,139.0,140.0};

    double[] testArray= new double[test1.length + test2.length];
    System.arraycopy(test1, 0, testArray, 0, test1.length);
    System.arraycopy(test2, 0, testArray, test1.length, test2.length);

    for(double d:testArray){
    Log.i(MAIN_DEBUG_TAG, "testArray "+d);
    }

      Random r = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < SERIES_NR; i++) {
      XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Demo series " + (i + 1));
      for (int k = 0; k < nr; k++) {

     // series.add(k, 120 + r.nextInt() % 100);
    series.add(k, testArray[k]);

    Log.i(MAIN_DEBUG_TAG, "series.add  "+k +"   "+test1[k]);

     }
    dataset.addSeries(series);        
    }         

        return dataset;
  }
```

Test1 array is repeated. If I remove the comments from series.add(k,120+ random......  it will genereated 2 series of data to plot.  Any help appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the same data points twice - `testArray[0]` to `testArray[9]` in both iterations of the outer loop. `k` always goes from `0` to `9`, and the current code doesn't rely on anything other than `k`:

```
// No sign of anything that changes between iterations of the outer loop
series.add(k, testArray[k]);
```

How about:

```
 series.add(k, testArray[k + i * nr]);
```

That way the first series will have `testArray[0]` to `testArray[9]`, and the second series will have `testArray[10]` to `testArray[19]`.

Comment: Bingo,  as usual, Jon's answer is succinct and correct.   Thanks Jon, you prevented some serious "head-banging".